# How to make 2 interfaces (of 2 different linux server) reachable to each other?

Tags: linux, networking

I have 2 Linux servers with **eth0: 561 VLAN**, and **eth1: 531 VLAN**

From both the system I can ping eth0 interface but not eth1 interface, I want to ping eth1.

Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two interfaces on two different VLANs won't talk *directly* with each other. They are in two (virtual) different networks/broadcast medium.

One of the solutions is changing the VLAN and IP address of one of the interfaces to the same VLAN/network of the other, which is not probably what you want.

The other solution is setting up the routing infra-structure/routing/firewalls to allow communication between the VLAN 561 and VLAN 531, and between the two IP addresses involved, however the particular steps are out of topic here. Talk with your network team.

To be fair enough, if both eth0 interfaces speak with each other, ip forwarding can be setup and specific routing can be done for doing want you want. I do not recommend creating special cases and subverting in such a way local routing and security: in case of problems, it will make the work of your network team much more difficult. Expose the problem to them.

Comment: If this answer answers your question, then mark ✓it as correct, else add more detail to your question about your setup. It just left me guessing. Then tell us what you have tried and what the results were.

Comment: Sorry, My bad, Problem was just with loose connection with one of the VLAN,